# partitions and sub partitions

Tags: mysql

The following `CREATE TABLE` statement to partition a table works as expected, without error.

```
CREATE TABLE `ox_data_archive_20120108` (
    `id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL,
    `creativeid` int unsigned NOT NULL,
    `zoneid` int unsigned NOT NULL,
    `datetime` datetime NOT NULL
) PARTITION BY LIST(to_days(datetime )) (
      PARTITION `1Jan10` VALUES IN (to_days('2010-01-01') ),
      PARTITION `2Jan10` VALUES IN (to_days('2010-01-02') ),
      PARTITION `3Jan10` VALUES IN (to_days('2010-01-03') )
  );
```

What I need to do is to create subpartitions based on date + zoneid. I tried the following:

```
CREATE TABLE mypart (
    `id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL,
    `creativeid` int unsigned NOT NULL,
    `zoneid` int unsigned NOT NULL,
    `datetime` datetime NOT NULL
) PARTITION BY LIST(to_days(datetime )) 
  SUBPARTITION BY KEY(zoneid) (
      PARTITION `1Jan10` VALUES IN (to_days('2010-01-01') )
        (Subpartition s1, Subpartition s2),
      PARTITION `2Jan10` VALUES IN (to_days('2010-01-02') ) 
        (Subpartition s3, Subpartition s4),
      PARTITION `3Jan10` VALUES IN (to_days('2010-01-03') )
        (Subpartition s5, Subpartition s6)
  );
```

Inserting into this table:

```
INSERT INTO mypart VALUES (1, 2, 3, '2012-01-31 04:10:03');
```

results in the following error:

> ERROR 1526 (HY000): Table has no partition for value 734898

My query expects to use the zoneid subpartition based on dates. Is it possible?

Comment: Expand on "does not work as expected". What do you expect? What actually happens?

Comment: Can not insert records in this table # insert into mypart values (1, 2, 3, '2012-01-31 04:10:03'); # ERROR 1526 (HY000): Table has no partition for value 734898

Comment: Please update the question with the error message. In general, respond to requests for clarifications by updating your post, rather than replying with a comment. For one thing, a question should be understandable without reading comments. For another, SO is a QA & site, not a forum, and comments aren't intended (nor are they well suited) for discussions.

Comment: So, you actually want one partition per day? Why?

Comment: What do you hope to accomplish with this partitioning scheme? What's the [overall goal](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/133817)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Contrary to your assertion that the first table works without error, inserting the sample data into it:

```
INSERT INTO `ox_data_archive_20120108` VALUES (1, 2, 3, '2012-01-31 04:10:03');
```

results in the same error as for the second table. The value given in the error (734898) happens to be the value for `to_days('2012-01-31')`. You get this error because you only have partitions for January 1<sup>st</sup> through 3<sup>rd</sup>, 2010. Both the day-of-month and the year for the sample data are outside the defined partitions. Instead of `TO_DAYS` (which returns the number of days from year 0 to the given date), you probably want [`DAYOFMONTH`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_dayofmonth). Since each partition is contiguous, a `RANGE` partition seems more appropriate than a `LIST`.

Off topic, you only need to specify separate subpartition definitions when you want to set options for the subpartitions. Since you're not doing that, a `SUBPARTITIONS 2` clause will do the same thing as your statement, but is simpler.

```
CREATE TABLE mypart (
    `id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL,
    `creativeid` int unsigned NOT NULL,
    `zoneid` int unsigned NOT NULL,
    `datetime` datetime NOT NULL
) PARTITION BY RANGE(DAYOFMONTH(`datetime`)) 
  SUBPARTITION BY KEY(zoneid) 
  SUBPARTITIONS 2 (
      PARTITION `01` VALUES LESS THAN 2, -- Note: 0 is valid day-of-month
      PARTITION `02` VALUES LESS THAN 3,
      PARTITION `03` VALUES LESS THAN 4,
      ...
  );
```